# PHP: How to send emails with multiple attachments found in the same server

Tags: php, email

Here are the codes that works by receiving multiple files from HTML form. I need your assistance on how I can do the same while taking attachment files from the same server directory and not from HTML form anymore. Thanks.

```
<?php
```

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

if(isset($_FILES) && (bool) $_FILES) {

```
$allowedExtensions = array("pdf","doc","docx","gif","jpeg","jpg","png","rtf","txt");

$files = array();
foreach($_FILES as $name=>$file) {
    $file_name = $file['name']; 
    $temp_name = $file['tmp_name'];
    $file_type = $file['type'];
    $path_parts = pathinfo($file_name);
    $ext = $path_parts['extension'];
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowedExtensions)) {
        die("File $file_name has the extensions $ext which is not allowed");
    }
    array_push($files,$file);
}

// email fields: to, from, subject, and so on
$to = "anold@insprogress.com";
$from = "we@insprogress.com"; 
$subject ="test attachment"; 
$message = "this is a test message";
$headers = "From: $from";


// boundary 
$semi_rand = md5(time()); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 
 
// headers for attachment 
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 
 
// multipart boundary 
$message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
$message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
 
// preparing attachments
for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
    $file = fopen($files[$x]['tmp_name'],"rb");
    $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]['tmp_name']));
    fclose($file);
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
    $name = $files[$x]['name'];
    $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$name\"\n" . 
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$name\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}

// send
 
$ok = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
if ($ok) { 
    echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
} else { 
    echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>"; 
}
```

}

?>

```
        <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the question you want to send the attachments available on the server current working directory.

thus the above file upload code can be removed from the code.

if the user wants to see the files present in the server you can make a [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) request system which will contact the server for the files present in the directory and show them to the user.

for the above task you can refer the [Directory Class functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.dir.php) to show the file names over the web page.

the above code for the attachments can be modified as:

```
$files = //the options selected by the user in an array
//don't forget to sanitize and check the data.
// preparing attachments
for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
    $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
    $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
    fclose($file);
...
```